# How to pass @click argument to action method?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I need to retrieve data from API. I try to pass an argument from @click to action method in `Vuex`. I'm dispatching action in `method()` but I don't know how to pass argument to `value` parameter. As far as I know action should be invoked in `mounted()` but again, I'm struggling with how to do it. This is what I produced but it doesn't work:

```
      // Component.vue
      <v-list-group
        v-for="item in items"
        :key="item.id"
        @click="setItemName(item.value)"
        no-action
        >

      methods: {
          setItemName(value) {
             this.$store.dispatch('custom/getAllAction', value) 
          }
      },

 
      // Vuex   
      const mutations = {
           getAll: (state, all) => state.allData = all, 
      }

      const actions = {
          async getAllAction({commit}, prod)
          {        
            const response = await axios.get(`https://localhost:44327/api/Items/allItems?product=${prod}`)
            commit('getAll', response.data)
          },
      }
```

Comment: It's done the way you did it. If the problem persists, please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. "action should be invoked in mounted()" - there's no such rule.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I found a bug in my Vuex store. I initially used Vuex `state` to hold a value from `setItemName(value)`. Then I passed it to action. With my new approach above I don't need it and forgot to remove it from action method.